# Variables appear to remain constant

Tags: pine-script

I have the below code but the variables Bullcor and Bearcor I have created seem to remain constantly at 0. What have I done wrong?

```
var Bullcor = 0
var Bearcor = 0

currency1 = input("EURUSD", title="Positive Correlation 1")

security1 = security(currency1,"15",close)

ema50s1 =ema(security1,50)

ema200s1 =ema(security1,200)

if ema50s1>ema200s1
    Bullcor + 1

if ema50s1<ema200s1
    Bearcor + 1
```

Comment: Try to use the operator `:=`. `Bullcor := Bullcor + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign where you stack the count of your if statements.
add `Bullcor := Bullcor + 1` as in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study("bull/bear count")
var Bullcor = 0
var Bearcor = 0

currency1 = input("EURUSD", title="Positive Correlation 1")

security1 = security(currency1,"15",close)

ema50s1 =ema(security1,50)

ema200s1 =ema(security1,200)

if ema50s1>ema200s1
    Bullcor := Bullcor + 1

if ema50s1<ema200s1
    Bearcor := Bearcor + 1

// debug:    
plot(Bullcor, color = color.green)
plot(Bearcor, color = color.red)
```